# always on wifi & data connection whenever it turned off it's automatically turn on

Tags: wi-fi

In Micromax A104 phone have always turned on WiFi & data connection whenever It turn off it's turned on automatically..pls solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about when the auto-trigger happens?(Like,right after pressing or when using any app)
Nevertheless,there are certain possibilities:

1. Virus attack-(I recommend a hard reset or flashing a stock ROM)
2. An app might be auto-triggering the switch-(Find the app causing the issue)
3. The faulty Hardware or the drivers itself(Go for a fix or replacement from the company if you have it under warranty)